# Can I use an alterative port for syslog if 514 is already taken?

Tags: networking, server, syslog, rsyslog

I'm looking to send our Load Balancer's logs to a syslog server. We already have an existing `Ubuntu 20.04 syslog server` and would like to use this rather than request to stand up a new server. However, it's already receiving syslog from another client on `port 514`.

I was checking around and I get conflicting info that I cannot use a different port and some says that I can. The load balancer doc I was reviewing doesn't state that I have to exclusively use port 514 for syslog.

My questions are:

1. If I use an alternative port for syslog, can I use 515, 516 and so
   on?
2. Are there any other considerations I need to take if I use any of
   the ports I mentioned?

Comment: A single `syslog` server can receive logs from multiple clients.

Comment: I know that. The question however is if I can use another port on that same server rather than 514.